# Why is this line char g = (char)(br.read()); getting skipped?

Tags: java

In this program, the line `char g = (char)(br.read())` is getting skipped whenever I run the program.After entering the age, if I enter gender as m, I am getting the error java.lang.NumberFormatException.

```
import java.io.*;
public class Tax
{
    public static void main()throws IOException
    {
        InputStreamReader isr  = new InputStreamReader(System.in);
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(isr);
        System.out.println("Enter age");
        int age = Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());
        System.out.println("Enter gender as m or f");
        char g = (char)(br.read());
        System.out.println("Enter Taxable Income");
        int ti = Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());
        double in;
        if (age > 65 || g == 'f')
        System.out.println("Wrong Category");
        else
        {
            if (ti <= 160000)
            in = 0;
            else if(ti > 160000 && ti<=500000)
            in = (ti - 160000) * (10.0/100.0);
            else if(ti > 500000 && ti<=800000)
            in = (ti - 50000) * (20.0/100.0) + 34000;
            else
            in = (ti - 800000) * (30.0/100.0) + 94000;
            System.out.println("Income Tax = " + in);
        }
    }
}
```

But if the program is modified as below ,i.e. if `char g = (char)(br.read());` is replaced by `String g = br.readLine()`, it works

```
import java.io.*;
public class Tax
{
    public static void main()throws IOException
    {
        InputStreamReader isr  = new InputStreamReader(System.in);
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(isr);
        System.out.println("Enter age");
        int age = Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());
        System.out.println("Enter gender as m or f");
        String g = br.readLine();
        System.out.println("Enter Taxable Income");
        int ti = Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());
        double in;
        if (age > 65 || g.equalsIgnoreCase("f"))
        System.out.println("Wrong Category");
        else
        {
            if (ti <= 160000)
            in = 0;
            else if(ti > 160000 && ti<=500000)
            in = (ti - 160000) * (10.0/100.0);
            else if(ti > 500000 && ti<=800000)
            in = (ti - 50000) * (20.0/100.0) + 34000;
            else
            in = (ti - 800000) * (30.0/100.0) + 94000;
            System.out.println("Income Tax = " + in);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: put the read and the readLine return value into their own variables and see what they are. It should tell you what's happening.

Answer (score 6):

The problem is that you're only reading a single character from the reader - leaving the line separator part still to be read.

So if the `BufferedReader` logically contains:

```
30\r\nm\r\n20
```

Then:

- Calling `readLine()` the first time will consume `"30\r\n"`.
- Calling `read()` will then consume `"m"` leaving `\r\n20`
- Calling `readLine()` the second time will consume `"\r\n"`, returning an empty string

If you actually *type* "30", hit return, then type "m20" and hit return, it will work - but obviously that's not what you want :)

Either use a scanner, or just use `readLine()` and check the contents of the line against "m" and "f".

Answer (score 2):

Try using scanner as in

```
     char g;
     Scanner scan = new Scanner (System.in);
     g = scan.nextChar();`
```

Answer (score 0):

you are only reading one byte that means if you write something like

```
m 22
```

this menas you have a space before the number and if you type

```
m
22
```

This means the rest of the line after `m` is blank.

This is how I would write it

```
Scanner in  = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.println("Enter age");
int age = in.nextInt(); in.nextLine();
System.out.println("Enter gender as m or f");
String mf = in.next(); in.nextLine();
System.out.println("Enter Taxable Income");
int ti = in.nextInt(); in.nextLine();
```